# ActiveRecord has_one where associated model has two belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models that are associated with each other in this way:

```rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, class_name: User.name
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home_address, class_name: Address.name
  belongs_to :work_address, class_name: Address.name
end
```

The User -> Address association works fine:

```rb
home_address = Address.new
#=> <Address id:1>

work_address = Address.new
#=> <Address id:2>

user = User.create!(home_address: home_address, work_address: work_address)
#=> <User id:1, home_address_id: 1, work_address_id: 2>

user.home_address
#=> <Address id:1>

user.work_address
#=> <Address id:2>
```

What I'm having trouble with is getting the `Address`'s `has_one` to work properly. At first I got an error that `User#address_id does not exist`, which makes sense because that's not the name of the foreign key field. It would be *either* `home_address_id` or `work_address_id` (and I added these FKs with a migration). But I wasn't sure how to let it know which address to use, until I learned that you can pass a scope into a `has_one` declaration:

```rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user,
    ->(address) { where(home_address_id: address.id).or(where(work_address_id: address.id)) },
    class_name: User.name
end
```

But this returns the same error as before: `Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.address_id does not exist`. This is confusing, because nowhere in that scope did I declare that I'm looking on `address_id`. I'm guessing the `has_one` implicitly has a foreign_key of :address_id, but I don't know how I'd set this because there are technically two, :home_address_id and :work_address_id.

I feel like I'm close here - how do I fix this has_one association?

## Update

My gut says that the solution here is to just create a `user` method that performs the query I'm looking to run, instead of declaring a `has_one`. It'd be great if `has_one` supports this functionality, but if not, I'll fall back to that.

```rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  def user
    User.find_by("home_address_id = ? OR work_address_id = ?", id, id)
  end
end
```

## Solution

Thanks to @max below! I ended up going with a solution based on his answer. I also use the `Enumerize` gem, which will come into play in the `Address` model.

```rb
class AddAddressTypeToAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  add_column :addresses, :address_type, :string
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, class_name: Address.name, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :home_address, -> { Address.home.order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: Address.name
  has_one :work_address, -> { Address.work.order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: Address.name
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  extend Enumerize

  TYPE_HOME = 'home'
  TYPE_WORK = 'work'
  TYPES = [TYPE_HOME, TYPE_WORK]

  enumerize :address_type, in: TYPES, scope: :shallow
  # Shallow scope allows us to call Address.home or Address.work

  validates_uniqueness_of :address_type, scope: :user_id, if: -> { address_type == TYPE_WORK }
  # I only want work address to be unique per user - it's ok if they enter multiple home addresses, we'll just retrieve the latest one. Unique to my use case.
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each association in Rails can just have a single foreign key because what you would need is in terms of SQL is:

```
JOINS users 
ON users.home_address_id = addresses.id OR users.work_address_id = addresses.id
```

Using a lambda to add a default scope for the association won't work here since ActiveRecord doesn't actually let you monkey with how it joins on an assocation level. Which is quite understandable if you consider how many different queries it generates and the number of edge cases that feature would cause.

If you REALLY want to go down the rabbit hole of having two different foreign keys on your users table you can solve it with Single Table Inheritance:

```
class AddTypeToAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :addresses, :type, :string
  end
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home_address, class_name: 'HomeAddress'
  belongs_to :work_address, class_name: 'WorkAddress'
end
```

```
class HomeAddress < Address
  has_one :user, foreign_key: :home_address_id
end
```

```
class WorkAddress < Address
  has_one :user, foreign_key: :work_address_id
end
```

But I would put the foreign key on the other table and use a one-to-many association:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
end
```

This lets you add as many address types as you want without borking your users table.

If you want to  limit the user to one home and one work address you would do:

```
class AddTypeToAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :addresses, :address_type, :integer, index: true, default: 0
    add_index :addresses, [:user_id, :address_type], unique: true
  end
end
```

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  enum address_type: {
    home: 0,
    work: 1
  }
  validates_uniqueness_of :type, scope: :user_id
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  has_one :home_address,
    -> { home },
    class_name: 'Address'
  has_one :work_address,
    -> { work },
    class_name: 'Address'
end
```

Comment: Solid tip on avoiding the situation entirely / using has_many :addresses. Another option (that I would also avoid/not recommend) is to `has_one :work_user, class_name: :user, foreign_key: :work_address_id` and `has_one :home_user, class_name: :user, foreign_key: :home_address_id` and then `def user; work_user || home_user; end`

Comment: @melcher Yeah, I thought about that for about 5 seconds and immediately decided it was a bad idea. :)

Comment: @max Thanks for the comprehensive answer! A few follow-ups:

1. Are there advantages to using :integer for that address_type field instead of just making it a :string column?
2. What's going on with the calls to `home` and `work` in the User has_one scopes?

Comment: @max Thought on those questions a bit and I think it's: 1. More compact db storage compared to strings, 2. Those are scopes defined in the address class right? i.e. `scope :home, -> { where(type: 0) }`

Comment: Strings vs integers for enums is one of those things that can be debated forever. There is the slight performance benefit to integers while strings are supposedly better for maintainence. I went with integers as thats what in the docs.

Comment: `enum` automatically generates scopes for each key in the enum.

Comment: (small) advantage to strings is if you have a data warehouse / BI tool it's more obvious what the values mean (rather than keeping the queries in that tool in sync with your data model)

Comment: @melcher yeah thats a pretty mcuh what I meant with maintainence. You can understand the data without the documentation. Another alternative is native enum columns (on Postgres) but thats a pain if you ever have to change the defintions.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @max. I lean towards strings myself. You've been a huge help! 